# Is there a dictionary where the frequency of a word appears?

Tags: dictionary, reference

Not so recently somebody posted a link to a dictionary that displays the frequency of a word. Well, I just forgot its name.

Of course there exists Duden, which however classifies words only in six possible levels of use. That dictionary I saw gives a better output and and takes as reference the word *der* (I don't say the 'article der', because I'm not sure they take the word as *only* meaning the article). 
Hence the output has, among otheres, the line:

> `<Input word>`. Index: 6

and that means, `<Input word>` is used about 2<sup>–6</sup>=1/64 times as often as *der*.

Could somebody refresh my memory?

Comment: I think you might be talking [about this word frequency list](http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html). According to the docs, `Dabei hat eine Grundform die Häufigkeitsklasse N, wenn diese Form etwa 2^N-mal seltener vorkommt als die häufigste Form.`

Comment: @blutorange No. I'm pretty sure there is a dictionary. However that list you provided will certainly help, so thanks.

Comment: "Durch die Anwendung dieser Verfahren auf das Deutsche Referenzkorpus DeReKo generieren wir verschiedenartige Grund- und Wortformenlisten des deutschen Sprachgebrauchs, z.B. die Lemmakandidatenliste mit 350.000 Einträgen für [elexiko – das Online-Wörterbuch zur deutschen Gegenwartssprache](http://www.ids-mannheim.de/elexiko/)." ?

Answer (score 3):

Here is an online-tool where you can enter a word and get its frequency-class together with lots of other interesting information:
http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/abfrage/

Here is a list of the 10,000 most frequent german words:
http://www.udel.edu/LLL/language/deutsch/top10000.pdf

Here you find links to similar lists for the top 10, top 100, top 1000 and top 10,000:
http://wortschatz.uni-leipzig.de/html/wliste.html

And here you find a list that is made from the DeReKo (deutscher Referent-Korpus = german reference corpus):
http://www1.ids-mannheim.de/kl/projekte/methoden/derewo.html